# How to loop over a series in order to use the consecutive data in Python

Tags: python, function, data-structures

I am trying to create a function where I get a new fractions file based on existing file, and then use the new fractions file to create the next fraction file.

the given is:
1. the two sets of input data.
2. the fractions of the first year

to find out:
1. the new fractions based on the computations in the code
2. use these new fractions in the subsequent year.

What I get is the same fractions for all the years. However, since I am new to python, I am not able to get the fractions to modify.

Any help is appreciated.

The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data
soyData = [186.65, 210.22, 283.21, 363.55, 254.74, 244.00]
maxPrecipData = [0.119182,0.143878, 0.043567, 0.129658, 0.158306, 0.199754]

def myFunction(year):    
   dbaseFraction2 = []
   forestFractions2= []
   agriFractions2= []
   savaFractions2= []

   for i in range(37):
      for j in range(49):

        t21 = -0.00000907728*soyData[year]
        t32 = 0.025700691 - 0.128202174*maxPrecipData[year]

        transMatrix= np.mat(((t21,0,0), (-t21,-t32,0),(0,t32,0)))
        areaMatrixOld = np.mat(((forestFractions2001[i][j],), (agriFractions2001[i][j],), (savaFractions2001[i][j],)))
        areaMatrixNew = areaMatrixOld + transMatrix*areaMatrixOld

        forestFractions2.append(areaMatrixNew[0])
        agriFractions2.append(areaMatrixNew[1])
        savaFractions2.append(areaMatrixNew[2]) 

        fractionfile = np.mat(((forestFractions2001[i][j],), (agriFractions2001[i][j],), (savaFractions2001[i][j],), (waterFractions2001[i][j],),))
        maxFraction = np.argmax(fractionfile)
        dbaseFraction2.append(maxFraction)


   maxField = np.reshape(dbaseFraction2, (37,49))

   for i in range(37):
      for j in range(49):
        if  maxField [i][j] == 0:
            landCover2[i][j] = 20.0
        elif maxField [i][j] == 1:
            landCover2[i][j] = 21.0
        elif maxField [i][j] == 2:
            landCover2[i][j] = 22.0
        elif maxField [i][j] == 3:
            landCover2[i][j] = 23.0

   fileName = 'landCover'+str(year+2001)+'.txt'

   np.savetxt(fileName,landCover2, fmt='%d')

   forest_Fractions2 = np.reshape(forestFractions2,(37,49))
   agri_Fractions2 = np.reshape(agriFractions2,(37,49))
   sava_Fractions2 = np.reshape(savaFractions2,(37,49))
   water_Fractions2 = np.reshape(waterFractions2001,(37,49))

   del dbaseFraction2[:]
   del forestFractions2[:]
   del agriFractions2[:]
   del savaFractions2[:]

   return

for i in range(30):
   myFunction(i)
```

Comment: Where does `myFunction()` end?  Could be that some indentation got lost when you pasted the code, there is a hanging `return` before the final `for` loop.

Comment: @cdarke  yes, i have edited that!

Comment: What are `forestFractions2001`, `agriFractions2001` and `waterFractions2001`? Where do they come from? Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: @mortysporty the fractions come from Land Cover data (MODIS). They are always less than 1 but not always mutually exhaustive. 
for example for a pixel, the values could be 
`forestFractions2001 = 0.4265
, agriFractions2001 = 0.3544 ,
waterFractions2001 = 0   
savaFractions2001 = 0.2191`